# Programmatically add buttons to array before viewDidLoad in swift

Tags: ios, swift

When using the storyboard, you can draw 2 buttons onto it, and add then add them to an array by creating:

```
@IBOutlet private var cardButtons: [UIButton]!
```

This outlet collection is now an array of both buttons that loads before viewDidLoad as a variable.

How do I create this array of buttons programmatically without using storyboard?

I've tried this but it gives me a declaration error:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cardButtons = [CardView]()
    let cardOne = CardView()
    cardButtons.append(cardOne)

    ...rest of viewController standard class
}
```

Comment: Use a singleton and load them through AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a several points of time in the ViewController's lifecycle where you might want to fill the cardButtons array. For example you could do this in viewDidLoad.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cardButtons = [CardView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let cardOne = CardView()
        cardButtons.append(cardOne)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that viewDidLoad is called every time the View is loaded into memory. In my example `cardOne` would be recreated every time. To avoid this you could store `cardOne` in a instance var, as you did initially.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cardButtons = [CardView]()
    let cardOne = CardView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cardButtons.append(cardOne)
    }
}
```

As I said, there several points of time in the ViewController's lifecycle where you might want to fill the cardButtons array. Other functions could be:

- `viewDidAppear()`, to fill the area every time the view appears.
- `init()`, if you are not using storyboard at all.

Comment: Perfect thanks - I ended up doing it slightly different than suggested, but this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let uiView: UI = {
        var ui:UI = UI()
        let cardOne = CardView()
        let cardTwo = CardView()
        ui.addButton(item: cardOne)
        ui.addButton(item: cardTwo)
        return ui
    }()
...rest of viewController standard class
}

class UI {
    var cardButtons = [CardView]()

    func addButton(button: CardView){
        cardButtons.append(button)
    }
}
```